# Magento 1.9 RWD remove (html, body height: 100%)

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, parallax

I discovered my:

```
html, body {
  /* height: 100%; */
```

causes problems with my [Parallax section.](http://www.meesfrenkelfrank.com/magento/en) Can i safely remove `height: 100%;` from the html and body-tag? Where is this style actually for?

Comment: Just to gotp `style.css` at your magento folder at location of 
/skin/frontend/mees-package/mees-theme/css line no 2673

Comment: but in generally, where is this style for? Doesn't it causes problems with the RWD theme?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can do

Just to goto `style.css` at your magento folder at location of 
`/skin/frontend/mees-package/mees-theme/css` line no 2673 and remove `height:100%`